# WebStorm: Possible to transpile of TypeScript File only when saving

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, transpiler

I'm using JavaScript and TypeScript in WebStorm and I'm concerned about WebStorm's transpile behaviour. It transpiles every time I made a change in the TypeScript files.

Is it possible to change that transpile mode, so that transpiling is only happening when I'm saving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Webstorm [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/new-watcher-dialog.html#immediateFileSynchronization), You can change the TypeScript transpiler compile behavior by unchecking the `immediate file synchronization` checkbox in Preferences > Tools > File Watchers > TypeScript dialog window.

[image]

If the `TypeScript` File Watcher isn't listed in the File Watchers list, you need to create it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using built-in Typescript compiler service rather than a file watcher, uncheck '`Track changes`' in Settings | Languages & frameworks | TypeScript and use '`Compile All`' action to run the compiler explicitly

Comment: JetBrains should add the "Immediate file synchronization" to the Languages & Framework TypeScript settings too!